# Bitmask conversion in Powershell

Tags: powershell, bitmask

I'm working with a bitmask that represents error codes. For example, a value of 3 (binary 11) indicates that errors 1 and 2 were encountered (binary 1 and 10). I'm looking for a function that converts this to an array automatically in powershell.

I've looked around the internet and couldn't find anything particular to this scenario. I've written a function that does this, but it's not very readable if the user isn't familiar with bitmasks.

**EDIT** To be specific, I'm looking for a function that takes 'raw' error bits and uses that to return an array of errors. For example:

`GetErrorList 3779`

returns an array containing:

`1, 2, 64, 128, 512, 1024, 2048`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set up a hashtable with translations for each bit and use the binary `AND` operator (`-band`) to find out what errors have been raised:

```
function Get-ErrorDescription {

    param([int]$ErrorBits)

    $ErrorTable = @{
        0x01 = "Error1"
        0x02 = "Error2"
        0x04 = "Error3"
        0x08 = "Error4"
        0x10 = "Error5"
        0x20 = "Error6"
    }

    foreach($ErrorCode in $ErrorTable.Keys | Sort-Object){
        if($ErrorBits -band $ErrorCode){
            $ErrorTable[$ErrorCode]
        }
    }
}
```

returns a string array of errors found, or `$null`

```
PS C:\> Get-ErrorDescription -ErrorBits 3
Error1
Error2
```

Comment: Thanks! Your implementation with the `-band` operator was what I was looking for.

Comment: You can take out "-eq $ErrorCode".  If the bits don't match, it will always be 0.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT:  I found a really cool way to do this with enum flags in Powershell 5:

```
[flags()] Enum ErrorTable
{
  Error1 = 0x01
  Error2 = 0x02
  Error3 = 0x04
  Error4 = 0x08
  Error5 = 0x10
  Error6 = 0x20
}

PS C:\> $errorcodes = [ErrorTable]'Error1,Error2'
PS C:\> $errorcodes
Error1, Error2
PS C:\> $errorcodes = [ErrorTable]3
PS C:\> $errorcodes
Error1, Error2
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across an issue recently very similar to the OP.  The question's a bit old, but this might help someone else.

As js2010 mentioned, you can use an [enumeration defined as a collection of bit flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_enum?view=powershell-7#enumerations-as-flags) to great effect:

```
[flags()] Enum ErrorTable {
    Error1 = 1
    Error2 = 2
    Error3 = 4
    Error4 = 8
    Error5 = 16
    Error6 = 32
    Error7 = 64
    Error8 = 128
    Error9 = 256
    Error10 = 512
    Error11 = 1024
    Error12 = 2048
}

function GetErrorList ([int]$ValueIn) {
    [ErrorTable]$ValueIn
}
```

Here GetErrorList is actually returning a string of errors, if you would rather an array, then change the single line in the function to:

```
[ErrorTable]$ValueIn -split ', '
```

This does not actually answer the exact question the OP asked, but that can be answered, without an enum, as follows (and surely there are more efficient and elegant methods):

```
function GetErrorListNumeric ([int]$ValueIn) {

    $s = [System.Convert]::ToString($ValueIn,2)
    $values = @()
    while ($s.length -ge 1) {
        if ($s[0] -eq '1') { $values += [Math]::Pow(2,$s.length-1) }
        $s = $s -replace '^.', ''
    }

    [array]::Reverse($values)
    $values

}
```

In my case I needed to convert the bit flags to longer message strings.  That won't work with an enum, but the values of the enum can be converted using a hash, like this:

```
$ErrorMessages = @{
    Error1 = 'error #1'
    Error2 = 'error #2'
    Error3 = 'error #4'
    Error4 = 'error #8'
    Error5 = 'error #16'
    Error6 = 'error #32'
    Error7 = 'error #64'
    Error8 = 'error #128'
    Error9 = 'error #256'
    Error10 = 'error #512'
    Error11 = 'error #1024'
    Error12 = 'error #2048'
}
```

Then, this function would convert the original bit mask into component error messages:

```
function GetErrorList ([int]$ValueIn) {
    $ErrorMessages[([ErrorTable]$ValueIn -split ', ')]
}
```